# Question about logic implications

Tags: logic

If $X\implies Y$ and $X\implies Z$, does that mean that $Y\implies Z$?

I think it does, but can anyone show this as a proof?

Thanks

Comment: $->$ means "implies". Correct?

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: Then the answer to your first question is no.

Comment: As an example (x = 4) -> (x is even), and (x = 4) -> (x > 3), but (x is even) -> (x > 3) is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Assume for purposes of contradiction that $X\implies Y$ and $X\implies Z$ means $Y \implies Z$.

$n= 3 \implies$ $n$ is prime.

$n = 3 \implies n$ is odd.

By our assumption, $n$ is prime $\implies n$ is odd. However, $2$ is an even prime.

This is a contradiction, so our initial assumption must be false.

Answer (score 0):

No.

What is true is $$[(X \rightarrow Y) \land (X \rightarrow Z)]\implies (X \rightarrow (Y \land Z))$$

In the case that you know $$(X\rightarrow Y) \land (Y\rightarrow Z),$$ then you can infer $$X \rightarrow Z.$$